# ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, matplotlib

Although this has come up as a topic before it has not been answered. I get the following import error I have just installed canopy from EPD and after I installed it, it keeps coming up with the following error:

```
    IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Eventloop or matplotlib integration failed. Is matplotlib installed?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.pyc in <lambda>(key)
    231         shell = self.shell
    232         if self.pylab:
--> 233             enable = lambda key: shell.enable_pylab(key, import_all=self.pylab_import_all)
    234             key = self.pylab
    235         elif self.matplotlib:

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all, welcome_message)
   2980         from IPython.core.pylabtools import import_pylab
   2981 
-> 2982         gui, backend = self.enable_matplotlib(gui)
   2983 
   2984         # We want to prevent the loading of pylab to pollute the user's

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   2941                 gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   2942 
-> 2943         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   2944         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   2945 

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    285     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
    286 
--> 287     import matplotlib.pyplot
    288     matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend(backend)
    289 

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 import matplotlib
---> 24 import matplotlib.colorbar
     25 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive
     26 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent, silent_list, is_string_like, is_numlike

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in <module>()
     27 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     28 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 29 import matplotlib.collections as collections
     30 import matplotlib.colors as colors
     31 import matplotlib.contour as contour

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in <module>()
     21 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     22 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 23 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     24 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     25 from matplotlib import _path

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in <module>()
     48 
     49 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 50 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     51 from matplotlib.path import Path
     52 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py in <module>()
      9 from matplotlib.path import Path
     10 from matplotlib import rcParams
---> 11 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     12 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     13 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT

/home/rhys/Documents/Uni_work/Year_2_research_placement/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
     51 import matplotlib
     52 from matplotlib import afm
---> 53 from matplotlib import ft2font
     54 from matplotlib import rcParams, get_cachedir
     55 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like

    ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried reinstalling matplotlib but it still comes up with the error and I cannot find the libpng16.so.16 file in \usr\local\lib, can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check Canopy's Package Manager. Make sure `matplotlib 1.3.1-8` package is installed.

An older version of `matplotlib` could be installed. Check the updates section and update your `canopy`.